# Should I use a Container/Service Fabric Guest Executable for a scheduled daily workload?

Tags: docker, containers, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-on-premises

This is a more general question about which types of payloads to host in a Container.  In our case we will use Service Fabric guest executables.  For this post I will only use the word Container to refer to both.  The reason I do this is they have similar properties and think more people may understand a container than a SF Guest Exe.

WebAPIs/Services that needs to scale are a good fit for containers, but this question is related to what we call a "Batch" job.  This nomenclature comes out of the old .bat files, but in our case we are using a .NET Framework or Core .exe (console apps).

Currently Windows Task Scheduler kicks off the batch running under a service account on a VM.  We want the processing to happen on a certain time of day or day of the week and not before or after.  There is not any real scaling here.  There is one instance which may or may not be multithreaded and on average they generally run between 2-15 minutes and then stop.  Some run longer some run shorter.  I understand there are limitations to this approach but this is the type of payload I'm discussing here.

As we modernize the Technology stack we are looking to use the Orchestrator as much as possible.  As a technologist I've always tried to understand the different tools in our tool belts and not use a tool just because that's the one I used last, instead use the correct tool for the task.

We started out by not writing any more .net console apps.  Instead we put the business logic of these  "batches" into WebApi's.  Then having the task scheduler call the API when it needed to perform its action.  If I put this into Service Fabric and host it my concern is that the system resources are consumed for 23 hours and 45 minutes a day when they are not being used.  That seems to be opposite of what you would expect when using a container.

Now if I could spin up a Service Fabric Guest Exe/Container on demand and then after it finishes destroy the instance of the app that could fit the need.  Then I could have the benefits of the orchestrator without the determent of having it consume resources all the time.  I would hope to retire the Batch Server (VM) as the hardware is usage is not optimized and instead add resources to the cluster.

**UPDATE**

Looking at Vaclav's Scalability Doco I think there might be a use case in here? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-scalability He uses a "Workload Manager Service" combined with CreateServiceAsync, to spin up an instance of the service on demand. I guess I would deploy the app to the image store but not create an instance of the app until needed. Then I need to figure out how to end it, is it as simple as changing the infinite loop in Program.cs?  The thing is it doesn't look like there is a Program.cs in a Guest Executable.

This looks like a way to run a package until completion, which was releases as part of 7.1.  But how do we start a second execution of the service?  I want to execute based on a request coming in.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/run-to-completion

Thoughts?

Comment: Sounds like [Azure Functions](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/functions/) might be a good fit?  Service Fabric has a constant baseline cost depending on the number and size of the *nodes* (5 recommended for production).  You can scale out dynamically from there onward, but it sounds like you just want to run a short job and only pay for the compute time used?

Comment: It is sorta like Functions, but I'm onPrem.

Comment: If having a running SF cluster is a given, you could lean on [Actor Reminders](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-timers-reminders#actor-reminders) or [hosted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio) within your WebAPI apps for job scheduling. The "dormant" resource consumption with these services would be negligible if they're just sat listening. I'd avoid using SF *solely* to schedule and run a single job once per day.

Comment: Yes, but then I'm still consuming the resources when I'm not using them.  Looking at a webapi that is not being used it is taking up 250 mg of ram.  I really want to spin up an app when its needed and get rid of it after.  I don't want to use a SF specific programming model so Actors are out.  Hosted Services might work but again I need to spin it up so we only use what we need.

Comment: In which case, having the jobs run within a WebAPI app might not be the best solution for you? A WebAPI app is usually a long running process and not really intended for hosting one-off batch jobs.

Comment: Looking at Vaclav's Scalability Doco I think this may work?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-concepts-scalability He uses a  "Workload Manager Service" combined with CreateServiceAsync, so I can spin up an instance of the service on demand.  So I  guess I would deploy the app to the image store but not create an instance of the app until needed.  Then I need to figure out how to end it, is it as simple as changing the infinite loop?